# Need Assistance with Curl Negating grep results

Tags: curl, grep

I'm trying to write a script that looks at a webpage.  When there is no sale, the site actually says "Thanks for checking but no sale today".  When there is a sale, the site simply posts items for sale.

When there is no sale, I don't care, when there is a sale I want the script to text me.  I'm also trying to run this script every minute.

I'm doing this on a mac in applescript.  I am by no means a programmer- I've cobbled this together over the past few weeks.  This is what I have- I'm running it via command line which is not necessarily what I want to do..

```
(curl -s 'https://wayfair.com' | grep -q "Thanks for checking") && osascript SendMessage.scpt 5555551234 https://wayfair.com
```

The contents of the SendMessage.scpt are

```
on run {targetBuddyPhone, targetMessage}
tell application “Messages”
set targetService to 1st account whose service type = iMessage
set targetBuddy to participant targetBuddyPhone of targetService
send targetMessage to targetBuddy
end tell
end run
```

Is there anyway to negate the data that grep is returning in the line above?  So if the site doesn't say "Thanks for checking", it could then proceed to text me (informing me that something is for sale).  If I could figure that out and put this into a bash, I could crontab it and it would only text if there was an item on the site.  Any assistance would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like all you need to do is change `&&` to `||` but you don't need a subshell either so also change `(...)` to `{...}`:

```
{ curl -s 'https://wayfair.com' | grep -q "Thanks for checking"; } || osascript SendMessage.scpt 5555551234 https://wayfair.com
```